# Why is .imageScale(.large) not big like in iOS stock apps?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swiftui

I am using the NavigationView with some navigationBarItems.
I have specified that the dimension (or scale) of both buttons has to be .large (like in the SwiftUI tutorials by Apple) but as you can see below they are not as big as the navigationBarItems in iOS stock apps like in Shortcuts or Wallet.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Images:

Shortcuts App by Apple

[image]

My View

[image]

```
struct GroupsTab: View {

  var addButton: some View {
      Button(action: {}) {
        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
          .imageScale(.large)

          // TO ACHIEVE THE SAME RESULT AS IN IOS I NEED TO SCALE THE IMAGE BY ABOUT 1.2 BUT IT BECOMES BLURRY
          //.scaleEffect(1.2)
      }
  }

  var editButton: some View {
    Button(action: {}) {
      Text("Edit")
        .imageScale(.large)
    }
  }

  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

      Text("hello world")

      .navigationBarItems(leading: editButton, trailing: addButton)
      .navigationBarTitle("Groups")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.imageScale(.large)` use `.font(.largeTitle)`

Comment: well that's a bit too big but thank you very much for the suggestion ! I will use another type of system font!

Comment: to achieve the same result you have to use .font(.title).scaleEffect(0.9)

Comment: of course, `.largeTitle` was an example I told you, you can use other options(like `.title` , `.headline` , `.subheadline`, ....) that fits your needs